# Hibernate Criteria Join problem

Tags: java, hibernate, join, criteria

I have a 2 classes that share a UUID and are uni-directionally mapped.  I use the UUID to group related rows, and this group shares many details (this is just an example):

```
@Entity @Table
class Something {
   @Id @Column("something_id")
   private Long id;

   private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn("uuid")
   private List<Detail> details = new LinkedList<Detail>(); 
}

@Entity @Table
class Detail {
   @Id @Column("detail_id")
   private Long id;
   private String value;
   private String uuid;
}
```

I'm attempting to use Criteria:

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Something.class).createAlias("details", "detail").add(Restrictions.eq("detail.value", someValue));
```

This is all fine and dandy, but I'm not getting results because of the join:

```
inner join DETAIL d1_ on this_.SOMETHING_ID=d1_.UUID
```

Is it possible to specify:

```
inner join DETAIL d1 on this_.UUID=d1.UUID
```

I would have expected the join to use the `@JoinColumn` annotaiton to find the column to join on.  I see that I can specify a join type, but I don't see a way to specify the actual column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected the join to use the `@JoinColumn` annotation to find the column to join on. I see that I can specify a join type, but I don't see a way to specify the actual column.

The join **is** using the `JoinColumn` annotation since it's joining on `d1_.UUID`. However, because you didn't specify the `referencedColumnName` element, the foreign key is assumed to refer to the primary key of the referenced table (`this_.SOMETHING_ID`), hence the obtained result.

In other words, try this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="uuid", referencedColumnName="uuid")
private List<Detail> details = new LinkedList<Detail>();
```

I'm not sure to understand the benefit but let's say it's another story.